# Unable to upload to Dropbox with carrierwave-dropbox without access token secret

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, dropbox, carrierwave, dropbox-api

I'm developing a Rails (4) application with multiple organizations, and each organization has a public facing form through which visitors can upload files. The challenge for me has been making it flexible enough to support multiple storage providers. My goal is for organizations to be able to choose from a number of providers, the first being Dropbox, as a destination for these uploads.

I'm using Devise for authentication so I'm also leveraging it and the `omniauth_dropbox_oauth2` for grabbing a user's credentials once they connect their Dropbox.

I'm using Carrierwave to manage my file uploads, but struggling to upload a file without providing the organization's (a Dropbox user) access token secret, something I don't get when I authorize the connect via oauth2.

I'm not even to the point of making my Carrierwave Uploader initialize a configuration dynamically for each user, so at this point I'm really just trying to understand where I'm going wrong configuring it with only my APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, and my ACCESS_TOKEN, which seems to be valid per their Support.

Not sure if it's worth sharing code here, but nonetheless here is where I'm at.

**Gemfile**

```
carrierwave (0.10.0)
carrierwave-aws (0.7.1)
  carrierwave (~> 0.7)
carrierwave-dropbox (1.0.2)
  carrierwave (~> 0.9)
  dropbox-sdk (~> 1.6)
```

**application_uploader.rb** (Carrierwave)

```
class ApplicationUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def initialize(*)
    super

    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.dropbox_app_key = ENV['DROPBOX_KEY']
      config.dropbox_app_secret = ENV['DROPBOX_SECRET']
      config.dropbox_access_token = ENV['MY_ACCESS_TOKEN']
      # config.dropbox_access_token_secret = ENV['MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
      # config.dropbox_user_id = <organization.id>
      config.dropbox_access_type = "app_folder"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm wondering if someone can shed some like on why uploads are failing without the `_access_token_secret`.

Comment: I suspect that CarrierWave is using OAuth 1, but you're using OAuth 2. OAuth 1 uses an OAuth token and OAuth token secret, while OAuth 2 uses a single access token.

Comment: You're right. After posting I started exploring forks of `carrierwave-dropbox` and found one with a "crude oauth2 implementation" that doesn't include the access token secret for authorization. A new issue with my user not being authenticated has popped up now, but once I square that away I'll likely post my own answer. Thanks @smarx.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Gemfile` change

```
gem 'carrierwave-dropbox'
```

to

```
gem 'carrierwave-dropbox', :git => 'https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox.git', :tag => 'v2.0.0.rc1'
```

then `bundle install`.